# attempt to index local 'f' (a nil value) Lua/Torch7

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to run an example from torch7 only to come across this error.

```
    sandesh@sandesh-H87M-D3H:~/Downloads/tutorials-master/2_supervised$ luajit doall.lua 
    ==> processing options
    ==> executing all
    ==> downloading dataset
    ==> using regular, full training data
    ==> loading dataset
    ==> preprocessing data
    ==> preprocessing data: colorspace RGB -> YUV
    ==> preprocessing data: normalize each feature (channel) globally
    ==> preprocessing data: normalize all three channels locally
    ==> verify statistics
    training data, y-channel, mean: 0.00067706172257129
    training data, y-channel, standard deviation: 0.39473240322794
    test data, y-channel, mean: -0.0010822884348063
    test data, y-channel, standard deviation: 0.38091408093043
    training data, u-channel, mean: -0.0048219975630079
    training data, u-channel, standard deviation: 0.29768662619471
    test data, u-channel, mean: -0.0030795217110624
    test data, u-channel, standard deviation: 0.22289780235542
    training data, v-channel, mean: 0.0036312269637064
    training data, v-channel, standard deviation: 0.25405592463897
    test data, v-channel, mean: 0.0033847450016769
    test data, v-channel, standard deviation: 0.20362829592977
    ==> visualizing data
    ==> define parameters
    ==> construct model
    ==> here is the model:
    nn.Sequential {
      [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> (7) -> (8) -> (9) -> (10) -> (11) -> (12) -> output]
      (1): nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(3 -> 64, 5x5)
      (2): nn.Tanh
      (3): nn.Sequential {
        [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> output]
        (1): nn.Square
        (2): nn.SpatialAveragePooling(2,2,2,2)
        (3): nn.MulConstant
        (4): nn.Sqrt
      }
      (4): nn.SpatialSubtractiveNormalization
      (5): nn.SpatialConvolutionMM(64 -> 64, 5x5)
      (6): nn.Tanh
      (7): nn.Sequential {
        [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> output]
        (1): nn.Square
        (2): nn.SpatialAveragePooling(2,2,2,2)
        (3): nn.MulConstant
        (4): nn.Sqrt
      }
      (8): nn.SpatialSubtractiveNormalization
      (9): nn.Reshape(1600)
      (10): nn.Linear(1600 -> 128)
      (11): nn.Tanh
      (12): nn.Linear(128 -> 10)
    }
    ==> define loss
    ==> here is the loss function:
    nn.ClassNLLCriterion
    ==> defining some tools
    luajit: /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/sys/init.lua:38: attempt to index local 'f' (a nil value)
    stack traceback:
        /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/sys/init.lua:38: in function 'execute'
        /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/sys/init.lua:71: in function 'uname'
        /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/Logger.lua:38: in function '__init'
        /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function 
        [C]: in function 'Logger'
        4_train.lua:60: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        doall.lua:70: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x00406670
```

I did not change any code in any of the lua files ...


This is the 4_train.lua file

```
 

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- This script demonstrates how to define a training procedure,
    -- irrespective of the model/loss functions chosen.
    --
    -- It shows how to:
    --   + construct mini-batches on the fly
    --   + define a closure to estimate (a noisy) loss
    --     function, as well as its derivatives wrt the parameters of the
    --     model to be trained
    --   + optimize the function, according to several optmization
    --     methods: SGD, L-BFGS.
    --
    -- Clement Farabet
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    require 'torch'   -- torch
    require 'xlua'    -- xlua provides useful tools, like progress bars
    require 'optim'   -- an optimization package, for online and batch methods

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- parse command line arguments
    if not opt then
       print '==> processing options'
       cmd = torch.CmdLine()
       cmd:text()
       cmd:text('SVHN Training/Optimization')
       cmd:text()
       cmd:text('Options:')
       cmd:option('-save', 'results', 'subdirectory to save/log experiments in')
       cmd:option('-visualize', false, 'visualize input data and weights during training')
       cmd:option('-plot', false, 'live plot')
       cmd:option('-optimization', 'SGD', 'optimization method: SGD | ASGD | CG | LBFGS')
       cmd:option('-learningRate', 1e-3, 'learning rate at t=0')
       cmd:option('-batchSize', 1, 'mini-batch size (1 = pure stochastic)')
       cmd:option('-weightDecay', 0, 'weight decay (SGD only)')
       cmd:option('-momentum', 0, 'momentum (SGD only)')
       cmd:option('-t0', 1, 'start averaging at t0 (ASGD only), in nb of epochs')
       cmd:option('-maxIter', 2, 'maximum nb of iterations for CG and LBFGS')
       cmd:text()
       opt = cmd:parse(arg or {})
    end

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- CUDA?
    if opt.type == 'cuda' then
       model:cuda()
       criterion:cuda()
    end

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print '==> defining some tools'

    -- classes
    classes = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'}

    -- This matrix records the current confusion across classes
    confusion = optim.ConfusionMatrix(classes)

    -- Log results to files
    trainLogger = optim.Logger(paths.concat(opt.save, 'train.log'))
    testLogger = optim.Logger(paths.concat(opt.save, 'test.log'))

    -- Retrieve parameters and gradients:
    -- this extracts and flattens all the trainable parameters of the mode
    -- into a 1-dim vector
    if model then
       parameters,gradParameters = model:getParameters()
    end

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print '==> configuring optimizer'

    if opt.optimization == 'CG' then
       optimState = {
          maxIter = opt.maxIter
       }
       optimMethod = optim.cg

    elseif opt.optimization == 'LBFGS' then
       optimState = {
          learningRate = opt.learningRate,
          maxIter = opt.maxIter,
          nCorrection = 10
       }
       optimMethod = optim.lbfgs

    elseif opt.optimization == 'SGD' then
       optimState = {
          learningRate = opt.learningRate,
          weightDecay = opt.weightDecay,
          momentum = opt.momentum,
          learningRateDecay = 1e-7
       }
       optimMethod = optim.sgd

    elseif opt.optimization == 'ASGD' then
       optimState = {
          eta0 = opt.learningRate,
          t0 = trsize * opt.t0
       }
       optimMethod = optim.asgd

    else
       error('unknown optimization method')
    end

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print '==> defining training procedure'

    function train()

       -- epoch tracker
       epoch = epoch or 1

       -- local vars
       local time = sys.clock()

       -- set model to training mode (for modules that differ in training and testing, like Dropout)
       model:training()

       -- shuffle at each epoch
       shuffle = torch.randperm(trsize)

       -- do one epoch
       print('==> doing epoch on training data:')
       print("==> online epoch # " .. epoch .. ' [batchSize = ' .. opt.batchSize .. ']')
       for t = 1,trainData:size(),opt.batchSize do
          -- disp progress
          xlua.progress(t, trainData:size())

          -- create mini batch
          local inputs = {}
          local targets = {}
          for i = t,math.min(t+opt.batchSize-1,trainData:size()) do
             -- load new sample
             local input = trainData.data[shuffle[i]]
             local target = trainData.labels[shuffle[i]]
             if opt.type == 'double' then input = input:double()
             elseif opt.type == 'cuda' then input = input:cuda() end
             table.insert(inputs, input)
             table.insert(targets, target)
          end

          -- create closure to evaluate f(X) and df/dX
          local feval = function(x)
                           -- get new parameters
                           if x ~= parameters then
                              parameters:copy(x)
                           end

                           -- reset gradients
                           gradParameters:zero()

                           -- f is the average of all criterions
                           local f = 0

                           -- evaluate function for complete mini batch
                           for i = 1,#inputs do
                              -- estimate f
                              local output = model:forward(inputs[i])
                              local err = criterion:forward(output, targets[i])
                              f = f + err

                              -- estimate df/dW
                              local df_do = criterion:backward(output, targets[i])
                              model:backward(inputs[i], df_do)

                              -- update confusion
                              confusion:add(output, targets[i])
                           end

                           -- normalize gradients and f(X)
                           gradParameters:div(#inputs)
                           f = f/#inputs

                           -- return f and df/dX
                           return f,gradParameters
                        end

          -- optimize on current mini-batch
          if optimMethod == optim.asgd then
             _,_,average = optimMethod(feval, parameters, optimState)
          else
             optimMethod(feval, parameters, optimState)
          end
       end

       -- time taken
       time = sys.clock() - time
       time = time / trainData:size()
       print("\n==> time to learn 1 sample = " .. (time*1000) .. 'ms')

       -- print confusion matrix
       print(confusion)

       -- update logger/plot
       trainLogger:add{['% mean class accuracy (train set)'] = confusion.totalValid * 100}
       if opt.plot then
          trainLogger:style{['% mean class accuracy (train set)'] = '-'}
          trainLogger:plot()
       end

       -- save/log current net
       local filename = paths.concat(opt.save, 'model.net')
       os.execute('mkdir -p ' .. sys.dirname(filename))
       print('==> saving model to '..filename)
       torch.save(filename, model)

       -- next epoch
       confusion:zero()
       epoch = epoch + 1
    end
```

This is doall.lua

```
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- This tutorial shows how to train different models on the street
    -- view house number dataset (SVHN),
    -- using multiple optimization techniques (SGD, ASGD, CG), and
    -- multiple types of models.
    --
    -- This script demonstrates a classical example of training 
    -- well-known models (convnet, MLP, logistic regression)
    -- on a 10-class classification problem. 
    --
    -- It illustrates several points:
    -- 1/ description of the model
    -- 2/ choice of a loss function (criterion) to minimize
    -- 3/ creation of a dataset as a simple Lua table
    -- 4/ description of training and test procedures
    --
    -- Clement Farabet
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    require 'torch'

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print '==> processing options'

    cmd = torch.CmdLine()
    cmd:text()
    cmd:text('SVHN Loss Function')
    cmd:text()
    cmd:text('Options:')
    -- global:
    cmd:option('-seed', 1, 'fixed input seed for repeatable experiments')
    cmd:option('-threads', 2, 'number of threads')
    -- data:
    cmd:option('-size', 'full', 'how many samples do we load: small | full | extra')
    -- model:
    cmd:option('-model', 'convnet', 'type of model to construct: linear | mlp | convnet')
    -- loss:
    cmd:option('-loss', 'nll', 'type of loss function to minimize: nll | mse | margin')
    -- training:
    cmd:option('-save', 'results', 'subdirectory to save/log experiments in')
    cmd:option('-plot', false, 'live plot')
    cmd:option('-optimization', 'SGD', 'optimization method: SGD | ASGD | CG | LBFGS')
    cmd:option('-learningRate', 1e-3, 'learning rate at t=0')
    cmd:option('-batchSize', 1, 'mini-batch size (1 = pure stochastic)')
    cmd:option('-weightDecay', 0, 'weight decay (SGD only)')
    cmd:option('-momentum', 0, 'momentum (SGD only)')
    cmd:option('-t0', 1, 'start averaging at t0 (ASGD only), in nb of epochs')
    cmd:option('-maxIter', 2, 'maximum nb of iterations for CG and LBFGS')
    cmd:option('-type', 'double', 'type: double | float | cuda')
    cmd:text()
    opt = cmd:parse(arg or {})

    -- nb of threads and fixed seed (for repeatable experiments)
    if opt.type == 'float' then
       print('==> switching to floats')
       torch.setdefaulttensortype('torch.FloatTensor')
    elseif opt.type == 'cuda' then
       print('==> switching to CUDA')
       require 'cunn'
       torch.setdefaulttensortype('torch.FloatTensor')
    end
    torch.setnumthreads(opt.threads)
    torch.manualSeed(opt.seed)

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print '==> executing all'

    dofile '1_data.lua'
    dofile '2_model.lua'
    dofile '3_loss.lua'
    dofile '4_train.lua'
    dofile '5_test.lua'

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    print '==> training!'

    while true do
       train()
       test()
    end
```

The git link is https://github.com/torch/tutorials/blob/master/2_supervised/4_train.lua


Also I'm not using cuda as I dont have a GPU

Comment: This is not a debugging service! You can't just paste code and an error message and expect others to do your work...

Answer (score 0):

I am currently playing with torch-rnn and stumbled accross the issue repeatedly. Check your input and see if the incorrect / no file was inputted. If the code worked before and no attempts were made to change it, it should be intact and it is your input that is problematic.

Answer (score -2):

I won't tell you what is wrong as you did not show any efforts to solve the problem yourself. But I will tell you how to proceed.

> luajit: /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/sys/init.lua:38:
>   attempt to index local 'f' (a nil value)
>       stack traceback:
>           /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/sys/init.lua:38: in function 'execute'
>           /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/sys/init.lua:71: in function 'uname'
>           /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/optim/Logger.lua:38: in function '__init'
>           /home/sandesh/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function 
>           [C]: in function 'Logger'

This tells you that some local f in init.lua line 38 is nil, which causes a problem. So open that file and find out where that f's value should come from and why it is nil. Then fix that. Also see if there is a more recent version of Torch that handles f being nil correctly. If not, change the code yourself, if possible. Otherwise try to stop this from happening by validating your inputs to torch.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, I'm getting this happening as a result of require 'paths' occasionally.